# Careers share / promote functionality

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, jobs

In the Careers 2.0 website, it would be nice to have a `Facebook` - `GooglePlus` - `Twitter` share buttons like it exists here.

I mean an easy way to promote the Careers website or a specific user profile through well know networks.

This idea came after creating my curriclum on careers and I was expecting to have a page or button where I could tell my friends "how awesome this site is " or "hey I've just created a profile" and therefore encourage people to join.

**Update**

Well, knowing that users need invitations to join the website (for the moment), I guess this is not yet the time for it.

Spreading the word is already possible through the invitations system, but if I'm not wrong, the invitations is not a default granted privilege.

Comment: such a great ... future request ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fine idea that we've considered before, but after having tried it out on other projects it just isn't worth cluttering up the UI and supporting the feature.  The alternative of copying the URL and pasting it into Twitter is marginally more difficult for the few people who would use the feature.  If we figure out a way to make sharing profiles core to our UX and user growth, then I'll tuck my tail and make it work.

But please do tell your friends how awesome the site is.  I've sent you some extra invites so you can do that.

Comment: OK, see my update. I agree that sharing profiles is not that important.